# How to convert Persian character in decimal value in c++?

Tags: c++, linux

I work with Persian language(UTF-8). I want to convert it to hex. but my problem is first How to convert Persian character in decimal value in c++ in Linux OS?(I used Qt creator)

Comment: Which character encoding is your text data using?  The answer will likely depend on that.

Comment: the Persian character( i think it is UTF8).-> ا ب پ  and so on. when i used int(ch) it does not return correct answer. for example for 'ف' it should return 1601 , but in Linux it returns wrong number

Comment: Assuming you have 8 bit `char`s, a single `char` can never have the value 1601. UTF-8 is a variable-width encoding. You might have to consider more than one byte to get a single “character”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert persian text to hex with this code

```
  byte[] yourStrBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("your encoding").GetBytes("your str");
  string hexStr = BitConverter.ToString(yourStrBytes).Replace("-", "");
```

Comment: thanks. but my c++ is poor. can you put the full example source code . I dont know the headers and so on... really sory and shame for me . thnks

Comment: I used Qchar.unicode and the problem is solved. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The characters you mention have a three-byte encoding. If you are storing UTF-8 in an array of char, then you need to convert each byte to hex. Otherwise you might want to convert the 3-byte UTF-8 encoding to UTF-16 (16-bit integer, similar to UCS-2) encoding, and display the hex value of that 16-bit result.

Comment: yes I convert each char to hex. my charterer is 2 byte ( i think not three). so how to defined a character type utf8 to set my variables?

Comment: may I use wchar_t for utf-8?

Comment: No, wchar_t is a 16 (or more) bit encoding. You could use 3 of them to store the three bytes, but that's not what wchar_t is intended for.

Comment: The UTF-8 encoding of the character  پ is 0xD9 0xBE 0x20, three bytes. If you have only two, you either have a different character or a different encoding.

Comment: In Linux systems there is an "od" (octal dump) utility which can dump hex bytes using this command: "od -t x1". Type that and provide it with your input to see the encoding.